# Controlling keyboard/mouse on Windows Pro

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I use Microsoft Excel 2010 and 2007 at work, mostly 2010.

My macro that controls keyboard keys and mouse pointer works on every Home version of Windows 8, 10, 11. Working well as well on 7.

It doesn't work on Pro with an alert message:

> Code execution has been interrupted

and the hi-lighted debug point is the controlling code.

Every other macro doesn't have any problem.

Is there some specific security option difference for PRO and can I turn it off?

```vb
' for 32 bit
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal j As Long, ByVal k As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

' for 64 bit
'Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As LongPtr, ByVal y As LongPtr) As LongPtr
' Public Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr, ByVal dx As LongPtr, ByVal dy As LongPtr, ByVal cButtons As LongPtr, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)

Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10



Call SetCursorPos(600, 350)
Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I deleted Windows Pro software to reset all and installed Home version to replace it. Windows randomly updated and it stopped working again.

Comment: It works in Excel 365 on Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2. Have no idea for you except Excel upgrade.

Comment: Is your Office installation on 64 bit? Anyhow using `Call` is useless in the code context. Please, try: `SetCursorPos 600, 350` `mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0` `mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0`. I am using right click because it is more probable to raise a context menu in any position of the cursor...

Comment: @FaneDuru `Call` is syntactic sugar - some people (not I) prefer it because it makes it clear that it is a function "call" because the parentheses must be present. However, simply removing the `Call` and the parentheses is unlikely to help the OP. Changing from `LEFTDOWN` to `RIGHTDOWN` is completely changing the behaviour of the code and does not address the issue posted

Comment: @CHill60 I am afraid that it is possible that you missed the point... Left or Right click is the same in terms of **working or not**, but if the code **really executes a click** in an empty space, on a form etc., **nothing may happen** and he is in danger to not know about its existence. Related to this aspect I wrote " it is more probable to raise a context menu in any position of the cursor".

Answer (score 0):

These are the notes I left my work colleagues on this very problem ...

> So something that has worked for days, months, weeks even years,
> suddenly produces this error message "Code execution has been
> interrupted"
>
> You have been no-where near Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Pause/Break for months, and
> yet here it is. Randomly.
>
> The solution is to click Debug then hit Ctrl-Pause/Break twice. F5 to
> run to completion. Save the workbook. Open. Try again. Magic. I kid
> you not

Edit: I can't remember where I found this so if anyone knows please comment so the original author is credited. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this many times before but I didn't mention it on my question. My bad. Any way it doesn't help

Comment: Did you follow the <i>exact</i>steps - I've never known this to not work, and I've come across the problem dozens of times, but the "solution" is very sensitive (e.g. Ctrl-Pause/Break three times and it breaks the fix)